# Парсинг ссылки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

скажите, а как с помощью регулярного выражения в документе сделать такую замену:

есть

<а href="адрес страницы1" title="тайл ссылки1">

<а href="адрес страницы2" title="тайл ссылки2">

<а href="адрес страницы3" title="тайл ссылки3">

заменить всё, что находится до содержимого тега "title". Чтоб получилось:

|тайл ссылки1">

|тайл ссылки2">

|тайл ссылки3">

сделал бы в нотпаде, но адреса ссылок разные, и требуется регулярное выражение ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

заменить 
<а.*?title="
на 
|

Comment: огромное спасибо!
оказывается, так просто )))

p.s. жаль, не хватает авторитета плюсануть в карму;)